# Не получается спарсить сайт dns-shop.ru

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Хотел попытаться получить последнюю страницу сайта и название товара, но получаю в ответ пустоту. Не могу понять, что я не так делаю.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page_num = 1
url =  'https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8a01d16404e77/smartfony/?p=%s&i=1&mode=list&brand=brand-apple' % page_num

page = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(page , 'html.parser')
max_page = soup.find('span' ," item edge mobile end").get_text()
print(max_page)

for txt in soup.findAll('h3').text:
    print (txt)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Администраторы `www.dns-shop.ru` решили защититься от "парсеров" и сделали сайт динамическим. Таким образом `requests.get(url).text` вернёт еще не выполненный скрипт:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=/ciez2a">
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var JSEncryptExports={};
(function(w){function e(a,b,c){null!=a&&("number"==typeof a?this.fromNumber(a,b,c):null==b&&"string"!=typeof a?this.fromString(a,256):this.fromString(a,b))}function m(){return new e(null)}function D(a,b,c,d,f,g){for(;0<=--g;){var h=b*this[a++]+c[d]+f;f=Math.floor(h/67108864);c[d++]=h&67108863}return f}function Y(a,b,c,d,f,g){var h=b&32767;for(b>>=15;0<=--g;){var k=this[a]&32767,e=this[a++]>>15,z=b*k+e*h,k=h*k+((z&32767)<<15)+c[d]+(f&1073741823);f=(k>>>30)+(z>>>15)+b*e+(f>>>30);c[d++]=k&1073741823}return f}
function Z(a,b,c,d,f,g){var h=b&16383;for(b>>=14;0<=--g;){var k=this[a]&16383,e=this[a++]>>14,z=b*k+e*h,k=h*k+((z&16383)<<14)+c[d]+f;f=(k>>28)+(z>>14)+b*e;c[d++]=k&268435455}return f}function T(a,b){var c=J[a.charCodeAt(b)];return null==c?-1:c}function A(a){var b=m();b.fromInt(a);return b}function K(a){var b=1,c;0!=(c=a>>>16)&&(a=c,b+=16);0!=(c=a>>8)&&(a=c,b+=8);0!=(c=a>>4)&&(a=c,b+=4);0!=(c=a>>2)&&(a=c,b+=2);0!=a>>1&&(b+=1);return b}function E(a){this.m=a}function F(a){this.m=a;this.mp=a.invDigit();
this.mpl=this.mp&32767;this.mph=this.mp>>15;this.um=(1<<a.DB-15)-1;this.mt2=2*a.t}function aa(a,b){return a&b}function L(a,b){return a|b}function U(a,b){return a^b}function V(a,b){return a&~b}function H(){}function W(a){return a}function G(a){this.r2=m();this.q3=m();e.ONE.dlShiftTo(2*a.t,this.r2);this.mu=this.r2.divide(a);this.m=a}function P(){this.j=this.i=0;this.S=[]}function M(){}function n(a,b){return new e(a,b)}function p(){this.n=null;this.e=0;this.coeff=this.dmq1=this.dmp1=this.q=this.p=this.d=
null}function Q(a){var b,c,d="";for(b=0;b+3<=a.length;b+=3)c=parseInt(a.substring(b,b+3),16),d+="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt(c>>6)+"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt(c&63);b+1==a.length?(c=parseInt(a.substring(b,b+1),16),d+="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt(c<<2)):b+2==a.length&&(c=parseInt(a.substring(b,b+2),16),d+="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt(c>>
2)+"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".charAt((c&3)<<4));for(;0<(d.length&3);)d+="=";return d}function ba(a){var b="",c,d=0,f;for(c=0;c<a.length&&"="!=a.charAt(c);++c)v="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/".indexOf(a.charAt(c)),0>v||(0==d?(b+="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(v>>2),f=v&3,d=1):1==d?(b+="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(f<<2|v>>4),f=v&15,d=2):2==d?(b+="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(f),
b+="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(v>>2),f=v&3,d=3):(b+="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(f<<2|v>>4),b+="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(v&15),d=0));1==d&&(b+="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(f<<2));return b}var q;"Microsoft Internet Explorer"==navigator.appName?(e.prototype.am=Y,q=30):"Netscape"!=navigator.appName?(e.prototype.am=D,q=26):(e.prototype.am=Z,q=28);e.prototype.DB=q;e.prototype.DM=(1<<q)-1;e.prototype.DV=1<<q;e.prototype.FV=Math.pow(2,
52);e.prototype.F1=52-q;e.prototype.F2=2*q-52;var J=[],r;q=48;for(r=0;9>=r;++r)J[q++]=r;q=97;for(r=10;36>r;++r)J[q++]=r;q=65;for(r=10;36>r;++r)J[q++]=r;E.prototype.convert=function(a){return 0>a.s||0<=a.compareTo(this.m)?a.mod(this.m):a};E.prototype.revert=function(a){return a};E.prototype.reduce=function(a){a.divRemTo(this.m,null,a)};E.prototype.mulTo=function(a,b,c){a.multiplyTo(b,c);this.reduce(c)};E.prototype.sqrTo=function(a,b){a.squareTo(b);this.reduce(b)};F.prototype.convert=function(a){var b=
m();a.abs().dlShiftTo(this.m.t,b);b.divRemTo(this.m,null,b);0>a.s&&0<b.compareTo(e.ZERO)&&this.m.subTo(b,b);return b};F.prototype.revert=function(a){var b=m();a.copyTo(b);this.reduce(b);return b};F.prototype.reduce=function(a){for(;a.t<=this.mt2;)a[a.t++]=0;for(var b=0;b<this.m.t;++b){var c=a[b]&32767,d=c*this.mpl+((c*this.mph+(a[b]>>15)*this.mpl&this.um)<<15)&a.DM,c=b+this.m.t;for(a[c]+=this.m.am(0,d,a,b,0,this.m.t);a[c]>=a.DV;)a[c]-=a.DV,a[++c]++}a.clamp();a.drShiftTo(this.m.t,a);0<=a.compareTo(this.m)&&
a.subTo(this.m,a)};F.prototype.mulTo=function(a,b,c){a.multiplyTo(b,c);this.reduce(c)};F.prototype.sqrTo=function(a,b){a.squareTo(b);this.reduce(b)};e.prototype.copyTo=function(a){for(var b=this.t-1;0<=b;--b)a[b]=this[b];a.t=this.t;a.s=this.s};e.prototype.fromInt=function(a){this.t=1;this.s=0>a?-1:0;0<a?this[0]=a:-1>a?this[0]=a+DV:this.t=0};e.prototype.fromString=function(a,b){var c;if(16==b)c=4;else if(8==b)c=3;else if(256==b)c=8;else if(2==b)c=1;else if(32==b)c=5;else if(4==b)c=2;else{this.fromRadix(a,
b);return}this.s=this.t=0;for(var d=a.length,f=!1,g=0;0<=--d;){var h=8==c?a[d]&255:T(a,d);0>h?"-"==a.charAt(d)&&(f=!0):(f=!1,0==g?this[this.t++]=h:g+c>this.DB?(this[this.t-1]|=(h&(1<<this.DB-g)-1)<<g,this[this.t++]=h>>this.DB-g):this[this.t-1]|=h<<g,g+=c,g>=this.DB&&(g-=this.DB))}8==c&&0!=(a[0]&128)&&(this.s=-1,0<g&&(this[this.t-1]|=(1<<this.DB-g)-1<<g));this.clamp();f&&e.ZERO.subTo(this,this)};e.prototype.clamp=function(){for(var a=this.s&this.DM;0<this.t&&this[this.t-1]==a;)--this.t};e.prototype.dlShiftTo=
function(a,b){var c;for(c=this.t-1;0<=c;--c)b[c+a]=this[c];for(c=a-1;0<=c;--c)b[c]=0;b.t=this.t+a;b.s=this.s};e.prototype.drShiftTo=function(a,b){for(var c=a;c<this.t;++c)b[c-a]=this[c];b.t=Math.max(this.t-a,0);b.s=this.s};e.prototype.lShiftTo=function(a,b){var c=a%this.DB,d=this.DB-c,f=(1<<d)-1,g=Math.floor(a/this.DB),h=this.s<<c&this.DM,k;for(k=this.t-1;0<=k;--k)b[k+g+1]=this[k]>>d|h,h=(this[k]&f)<<c;for(k=g-1;0<=k;--k)b[k]=0;b[g]=h;b.t=this.t+g+1;b.s=this.s;b.clamp()};e.prototype.rShiftTo=function(a,
b){b.s=this.s;var c=Math.floor(a/this.DB);if(c>=this.t)b.t=0;else{var d=a%this.DB,f=this.DB-d,g=(1<<d)-1;b[0]=this[c]>>d;for(var h=c+1;h<this.t;++h)b[h-c-1]|=(this[h]&g)<<f,b[h-c]=this[h]>>d;0<d&&(b[this.t-c-1]|=(this.s&g)<<f);b.t=this.t-c;b.clamp()}};e.prototype.subTo=function(a,b){for(var c=0,d=0,f=Math.min(a.t,this.t);c<f;)d+=this[c]-a[c],b[c++]=d&this.DM,d>>=this.DB;if(a.t<this.t){for(d-=a.s;c<this.t;)d+=this[c],b[c++]=d&this.DM,d>>=this.DB;d+=this.s}else{for(d+=this.s;c<a.t;)d-=a[c],b[c++]=d&
this.DM,d>>=this.DB;d-=a.s}b.s=0>d?-1:0;-1>d?b[c++]=this.DV+d:0<d&&(b[c++]=d);b.t=c;b.clamp()};e.prototype.multiplyTo=function(a,b){var c=this.abs(),d=a.abs(),f=c.t;for(b.t=f+d.t;0<=--f;)b[f]=0;for(f=0;f<d.t;++f)b[f+c.t]=c.am(0,d[f],b,f,0,c.t);b.s=0;b.clamp();this.s!=a.s&&e.ZERO.subTo(b,b)};e.prototype.squareTo=function(a){for(var b=this.abs(),c=a.t=2*b.t;0<=--c;)a[c]=0;for(c=0;c<b.t-1;++c){var d=b.am(c,b[c],a,2*c,0,1);(a[c+b.t]+=b.am(c+1,2*b[c],a,2*c+1,d,b.t-c-1))>=b.DV&&(a[c+b.t]-=b.DV,a[c+b.t+
1]=1)}0<a.t&&(a[a.t-1]+=b.am(c,b[c],a,2*c,0,1));a.s=0;a.clamp()};e.prototype.divRemTo=function(a,b,c){var d=a.abs();if(!(0>=d.t)){var f=this.abs();if(f.t<d.t)null!=b&&b.fromInt(0),null!=c&&this.copyTo(c);else{null==c&&(c=m());var g=m(),h=this.s;a=a.s;var k=this.DB-K(d[d.t-1]);0<k?(d.lShiftTo(k,g),f.lShiftTo(k,c)):(d.copyTo(g),f.copyTo(c));d=g.t;f=g[d-1];if(0!=f){var x=f*(1<<this.F1)+(1<d?g[d-2]>>this.F2:0),z=this.FV/x,x=(1<<this.F1)/x,l=1<<this.F2,t=c.t,p=t-d,B=null==b?m():b;g.dlShiftTo(p,B);0<=c.compareTo(B)&&
(c[c.t++]=1,c.subTo(B,c));

/* обрезано ... */
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Чтобы обойти это можно воспользоваться модулем Selenium, который откроет окно настоящего браузера для парсинга страницы:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html

page_num = 1
url = 'https://www.dns-shop.ru/catalog/17a8a01d16404e77/smartfony/?p={}&i=1&mode=list&brand=brand-apple'.format(page_num)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

content = driver.page_source
tree = html.fromstring(content)

print(tree.xpath('//span[@class=" item edge"]')[0].attrib)

last_page = tree.xpath('//span[@class=" item edge"]')[0].attrib.get('data-page-number')

print(last_page)
```

результат:

```
{'class': ' item edge', 'data-role': 'page-handler', 'data-page-number': '6'}
6
```